# CentOS 6.7 サーバー構築について

Tags: linux, centos, network

今回、初めてサーバー構築の勉強をしてみようと思い、古いPCにWindowsXPをアンインストールして新しくCentOS6.7をインストールしました(i386 Live-CDを使用)。
いろいろなサイトを見て設定していこうと思ったのですが最初の段階で躓いてしまいまして質問させていただきます。

ネットワーク設定をするところなのですが、どのサイトを見ても

> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

を編集するとあるのですが、「ifcfg-lo」しか存在しません。

しかし

> # ifconfig

で確認すると「eth-lo」「eth0」ともに表示されます。

network-scripts/にifcfg-eth0を勝手に作ってみたのですが、そうするとネットワークに繋がらない
？状態になってしまいます。

かれこれ４，５回初期化しては試して...を繰り返しているのですが全くわからない状態です。
本当の初心者でして...

固定IPアドレスの設定だとか、DNS、NICなどもちょっとづつ調べつつやってはいるんですが、まだまださっぱりな状態です。

この「ifcfg-eth0」は勝手に作っていいものなんですか？
また、初心者におすすめの解説サイト、書籍なども合わせて教えていただければ幸いです...

凄くくだらない質問だとは思いますが、よろしくお願い致します。

12/4 18:00追記
take88様
コメントありがとう御座います。
何度も試している中でのことなので詳しくは覚えていないんです。すいません。。。
しかし、先ほどGUIのネットワーク接続を開くとeth-0が発見してましたので、そこからIPなどを設定して同じネットワーク環境ならSSH接続できるようになりました！
固定IPの指定が間違っていたのかもしれません・・・

初心者なので、これからも質問してしまうかもしれませんが、その時はどうぞよろしくお願い致します！

Comment: 元から繋がらないのではなくて、ifcfg-eth0を作ったらつながらなくなったのですか？ifcfg-eth0を作ってからどのような操作をしたのか、表示されたメッセージ、ifcfg-eth0の内容など 質問に追記できますでしょうか。

Comment: 解決済みですね? https://teratail.com/questions/21707

Answer (score 1):

CentOSのインストーラはネットワークを自動設定しないので、インストール途中で明示的にネットワーク設定を行う必要があります。

さらに、その設定画面でも初期状態ではネットワークが自動的に有効にならないようになっていますので、ネットワークを有効にするよう項目を変更する必要があります。

Answer (score 0):

解決できました！

teratail.com/questions/21707